# How to create an overview of deleted branches in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a quick way to get an overview of all deleted branches, preferably using the revision graph? Let's assume I don't know the names of the deleted branches and the moment of deletion.

I tried a few things:

- Opening a revision graph in the branches directory from within the repo browser: the graph doesn't seem to show all deleted branches.
- Open a log in the branches directory from within the repo browser: here I can filter on everything but on Actions, which makes it not possible to filter out the delete actions for finding deleted branches.

Answer (score 3):

If I view SVN Log and type 'Deleted' into the filter, I get nothing but revisions with deletes in them. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that works, great. I figured that filtering on the word 'Deleted' would only filter out revisions having this word in their comments, but this is apparently not the case.

Comment: This solution shows all _Deleted_ actions (including file deletions within branches), I'm looking for a way to get a historic overview of only deleted branches.